# Python reverse sort wrong answer?

Tags: python, sorting

I'm solving a problem at Codility and at one step I needed to reverse sort a list of chars of digits. But python returned a very surprising result (at least for me)

Here is code:

`N = 231
result = [str(x) for x in str(N)]
result.reverse()
print(result)`

And print result is:

> ['1', '3', '2']

But when I used **result.sort()** before result.reverse() it returns correct result? Does anyone has any idea ?

Comment: `reverse` means reverse, not "sort in reverse order".

Comment: Ok, ok  sorry and thank you :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.reverse()` reverses the list. It does not *sort* it in reverse. Use `result.sort(reverse=True)`.